# Bind <select> opgroup label value along with a selected option in Chosen plugin

Tags: knockout.js, html-select, jquery-chosen

I have an html `select` that is view-model bound via KnockoutJS and is rendered as [harvest chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) plugin via a custom binding.

The select markup is:

```
<select class="chzn-select" data-bind="foreach: ControllersAndActions, selectedOptions: NewPermissionCAs, chosen: { PlaceholderText: 'Select', AddPlaceholder: true, ChosenOptions: {allow_single_deselect: true} }">
   <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: ControllerName}, foreach: Actions">
        <option data-bind="text: $data"></option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

A custom chosen-enabling binding I use is:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var attrList = { placeholderText: options.PlaceholderText };
        $.extend(attrList, allBindings.chosen);
        if (options.AddPlaceholder) {
            $(element).attr('data-placeholder', attrList.placeholderText).addClass('chzn-select');
        } else {
            $(element).addClass('chzn-select');
        }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};
        $(element).chosen(options.ChosenOptions);
        $(element).trigger("liszt:updated");
    }
};
```

Whenever `NewPermissionCAs` observable changes (it does when I select something via "chosen" gui), a function gets triggered that is supposed to save the new value to the server.

The problem is that the server needs both - option group label data, as well as the option value selected.

How can I retrieve option group label of a group the selected option is in in my function code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have figured it out - needed to concatinate both group name and option value in the `value` attribute of the  element like this:

```
<option data-bind="text: $data, attr: { value: $parent.ControllerName + ';' + $data }"></option>
```